# Don't understand the stack without the setTimeout 0

Tags: javascript, stack, settimeout

I have a question regarding the stack and setTimeout 0.
This code above makes the desired output, but I don't understand why without setting timeout to 0 "....calculating" is not outputted.
Because I think even without the timeout the on the stack would be "....calculating" then goes to function countUp and the for loop and if this is finished then there would be written "Ready to calculate again"
But why doesn't happen this without setTimeout 0 ?

```
function countUp() {
    var result;
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        result = i;
    }
    document.getElementById('status').innerText = 'Ready To Calculate Again';
}

function callback() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerText = '...calculating';
    var wait = window.setTimeout(function() {
        countUp();
    }, 0);
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', callback);
```

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do. The `for()` loop in `countUp()` is doing nothing but looping from 0 to 1000000000 and setting result to the current increment and your  `setTimeout()` is set to 0 milliseconds.

Comment: I was about to create a runnable snippet from your code but all the code did was displaying "Ready To Calculate Again" and that doesn't match your description. So I think you should edit the question and create the snippet yourself, possibly with two versions (since you describe having two different behaviours).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser do reflow and repaint between tasks in event queue
If you call countUp without setTimeout then countUp will be invoked in scope of callback task, so redraw in browser will be after countUp is finished.
So you will get '...calculating' and 'Ready To Calculate Again' at once.
But they should be displayed in different moments of time. So to allow browser to make redraw and display ...calculating we put countUp call in event queue as separate task with setTimeout.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was an answer, that I didn't found in last two days!